# How can I add custom breakpoint in Bootstrap 4 and use it for both up and down?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

How can I add custom variable in Bootstrap 4 and use it as a breakpoint for both up and down?

Breakpoints are used like this

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
   // 
}
```

I can add custom size (they need to be sorted otherwise it is error)

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
    xs: 0,
    sm: 576px,
    md: 768px,
    mycustomvar: 850px,
    lg: 992px,
    xl: 1200px
);
```

And I tried to use them

```
.current-menu-item {
   @include media-breakpoint-up(mycustomvar) {
       font-size: 2222px;
   }
   @include media-breakpoint-down(mycustomvar) {
       font-size: 1111px;
   }
}
```

This seems to be working for up, I get

```
@media (min-width: 850px) {
    .current-menu-item {
        font-size: 2222px;
    }
}
```

But for down it fails with wrong breakpoint

```
@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .current-menu-item {
        font-size: 11111px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When there is another breakpoint below, Bootstrap subtracts .02px when constructing the media query. Otherwise you'd have *overlapping* @media queries like this...

```
// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { ... }

// Medium devices (tablets, less than 992px)
@media (max-width: 992px) { ... }
```

Remember, any breakpoint *starts* at the given `px` width, so the next down smaller breakpoint must be **less than** the min `px` width of the larger breakpoint. [Read more in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints)

Here's the Bootstrap 4 `breakpoint-max` @function:

```
@function breakpoint-max($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  $next: breakpoint-next($name, $breakpoints);
  @return if($next, breakpoint-min($next, $breakpoints) - .02px, null);
}
```

If you want to go ahead an have overlapping media queries for the custom breakpoint, override the `bootstrap-max` function (removing the .02px subtraction)...

```
@function breakpoint-max($name, $breakpoints: $grid-breakpoints) {
  $next: breakpoint-next($name, $breakpoints);
  @return if($next, breakpoint-min($next, $breakpoints), null);
}
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/l4R9tnxyBx)

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. Hm I am not sure, this seems like a hack. Why doesn't Bootstrap calculate breakpoints according to $grid-breakpoints? Also it would be more cleaner to just write the usual syntax for breakpoints in case customizations outside grid breakpoints are necessary, currently I have both Bootstrap and usual @media definitions in SCSS files...

Comment: I dont really understand the question. Bootstrap *does* calc breakpoint using grid-breakpoints as you can see in the function. It just makes an adjustment of .02px to prevent overlapping breakpoint ranges as explained above. I think your question was why "for down it fails with wrong breakpoint?" which I think has been answered.